# Moving the deformation gradient tensor in tensor equation

Tags: tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics

Often, I see the deformation gradient tensor being moved in second-order tensors equations. When it is moved, it is simply transposed. An example from my textbook ($F$ is the deformation gradient, $v$ a vector):

$(F.v)(F.v)=v.F^{T}.F.v=v.C.v $

But I wonder what property makes that possible ? If I am not wrong, moving any second-order tensor in a tensor equation is normally not allowed:

$ABCD =/=AC^{T}BD$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily explained by writing out the products in full

$$
(Fv)^{T}(Fv) = \sum_{ijk} F_{ij} v_j F_{ik} v_k = \sum_{ijk}v_j F_{ij} F_{ik} v_k = \sum_{ijk} v_j F_{ji}^T F_{ik} v_k = v F^T Fv
$$

Comment: For me writing as such in indicial notation seems like magic. Does that mean I can only take the transpose in vectors equations ? It wouldn't work for multiple second-order products ?

Comment: Also, how did you move your vector before the first $F_{ij}$ since it would result in non-allowed vector-matrix product $\begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix} * \begin{matrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{matrix}$

Comment: It will work with second rank tensors, provided the product is between the correct indices.

Comment: I've edited the above to include the transpose that makes the equation correct if we make the tensors higher rank.

Comment: As for how I commuted v and F, note that the product in the sum is between numbers, not matrices, and the product of two numbers commute.

Comment: What prevents you from stopping here   :$\sum_{ijk}v_j F_{ij} F_{ik} v_k$ in which case you get $vFFv$ ?!

Comment: Note that thr matrix product is $\sum_j A_ij B_jk$ look at the indices, the product is over adjacent j's. That is, the sum is over the collums of A and the rows of B. You cannot move from indices notation to matrix notation until all summed indices are adjacent, or you use brackets and transposes to fix it.

Comment: I suggest you get out a book on tensors and learn Einstein notation, ir will probably help.

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually practiced indices notation, but I have a hard time getting the point of it. Your answers really helped!